# Auto completed text view to filter the items present in the arraylist in android

Tags: android

I have Auto completed text view,i want to filter the items present in the listcli arraylist.i enter the text "te" means it shows text as Apple test,Dmn test,Testing,Test 124 etc.But i want to show only Testing,Test 124 etc only.How can i filter these text?Also after enter the text,i click the next button in keyboard it doesn't go for the next edit text field,How do control this the keyboard?

```
client.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                cli = client.getText().toString();
                actionvalues = ReadXML.getXmlData("WebService", Base_Url
                        + "GetclientList?xml=" + client.getText().toString(),
                        "ClientList", "Client", "CID", "ClientName");

                for (int i = 0; i < actionvalues.size(); i++) {
                    String client = actionvalues.get(i).get("ClientName")
                            .toString();
```

listcli is array list

```
listcli.add(client);

            }


            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SalesActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,listcli);
            client.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let arr[20] be the array of strings for autocomplete text view

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

          while(bool){

              s2=ac.getText().toString();
          if(s1!=s2 && s2.length()>=1){
                              for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
                               {
                                  int k=arr[i].indexOf(s2);
                                  if(s2==0){lst.add(search[i]);}<---lst is the list of strings to be displayed

                                }
                                }
                               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     adapter.clear();
                     for(int z=0;z<k;z++){

                         adapter.add(s[z]);
                     }
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                }
            });
         }}).start();
```